# Like, Share and Tweet. Is a Facebook and Twitter account required?

Tags: social-networking

I am planning on using the following social networking elements on my website:

- Facebook Like
- Facebook Share
- Tweet

Do I need a facebook and twitter account to use the above on my website so that users can either like, share or tweet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the users need accounts to like, share.

You will however need an apikey for the users to log into your app.

**For Facebook:**

You get this key by creating a new app @ 
http://www.facebook.com/developers
 - > Apps

Hope this helps!